# jQuery Animation not smooth when using animate width: 'toggle' with horizontal accordion menu

Tags: jquery, toggle, accordion

Not sure why, but my animation is a bit choppy when returning back to it's original state. Below is a link to the jsfiddle for this:

```
$('.char-more').click(function () {
    var $curr = $(this).closest('.widgetWrap'),
        $prevActive = $('.activeClass').not($curr);
    //$prevActive.removeClass('activeClass');
    $prevActive.find('.acontent').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        queue: false
    });
    $curr.toggleClass('activeClass').find('.acontent').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, {
        duration: 500,
        easing: 'easeOutExpo',
        queue: false,
        complete: function () {
            $prevActive.removeClass('activeClass');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EKZq8/3/

Any ideas would be great!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EKZq8/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of your padding. It is smooth if you set it to zero:

```
.widgetWrap > .acontent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F7F7F7;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 93px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 240px;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/EKZq8/6/

Comment: Thank you Basarat Ali! Yeah, I couldn't figure out why it was shifting the divs a couple of pixels each it animated...Your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent)? or [Bootstrap Collapse](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)? You could easily reverse engineer to be horizontal. Failing that you could use CSS3 transitions to perform the animations this would be smooth as then if you need old browser support you could implement the jQuery version as a fallback.

Comment: should be a comment. I didnt do -1

Comment: Wanted to avoid depending on jQuery UI. Bootstrap is not an option